# Riemann integrability in not sequentially complete LCS?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

For $E$ any Hausdorff locally convex space, I have been wondering whether Riemann integrability of all continuous functions $f:[\,0,1\,]\to E$ implies that $E$ be sequentially complete. For example, consider $E=c_0(\mathbb N_0)_\sigma$ , the space $c_0(\mathbb N_0)$ of (say real) sequences converging to zero equipped with the weak topology $\sigma(c_0,\ell^1)$ . Then $E$ is *not* sequentially complete since the Cauchy sequence $\langle\kern.5mm x_i:i\in\mathbb N_0\kern.4mm\rangle$ , where $x_i(j)=1$ for $j\le i$ and $x_i(j)=0$ otherwise, is not convergent in $E$ . Does there exist a continuous function $f:[\,0,1\,]\to E$ which is not Riemann integrable?

Note that Riemann integrability of a continuous function $f:[\,0,1\,]\to E$ means that there is $x$ in $E$ such that for every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ there is some $n_0\in\mathbb Z^+$ such that $m^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^{\,m}f(n\,m^{-1})\in V$ for all $m\in\mathbb Z$ with $m\ge n_0$ .

Comment: The question has been answered in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151148/is-sequential-completeness-of-lcs-strictly-stronger-that-riemann-integrability-o/151170#151170 .